# Can someone explain why this test shows that jquery $.each is faster than native for?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, each

I am running the following test in my browser console in Chrome. I wanted to see how much faster native for is, only to find out that the results are showing jquery $each to be faster? I know this is not true but i would like an explanation if possible.

```
var array = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    array[i] = 0;
}

console.time('native');
var l = array.length;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    array[i] = i;
}
console.timeEnd('native');

console.time('jquery');
$.each(array, function(i) {
    array[i] = i;
});
console.timeEnd('jquery');

native: 26.160ms
jquery: 5.665ms
```

If i put the same code inside a setTimeout() then the results are like this:

```
native: 0.123ms
jquery: 0.885ms
```

Comment: They aren't really equivalent as the values of `i` are calculated in completely different ways.

Comment: So there is a problem with the test code you mean?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a fair test as you have changed multiple factors.

Comment: @Quentin what would be the correct code to test with?

Comment: for comparison of methods: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L282

Comment: You should use [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method instead of for loop. It's more similar to jQuery.each() method.

Comment: Chrome: [Visualize JavaScript performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/rendering-tools/js-execution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to Chrome compiling functions and not compiling console input outside of functions. Compiled functions run a lot faster. `jQuery.each` is already compiled (at the time jQuery was included on the page).

Wrap your first test inside of an immediately-invoked function (which Chrome can compile before execution), and you'll see very similar results:

```
console.time('native');
(function(){
    var l = array.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }
})();
console.timeEnd('native');

console.time('jquery');
// ... unchanged
console.timeEnd('jquery');

native: 3.518ms
jquery: 3.308ms
```

That's why you were seeing radically difference results when you put code inside of a function in `setTimeout` like `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 1)`. The code inside the function got compiled and ran a lot faster.

Comment: indeed the results are almost the same now, also this answer i believe is showing me the way and where to look next